# Star Schema - Loans Overdue Dates Modeling

Tags: dimensional-modeling

I have a table with three columns:

- CALC_DATE
- LOAN_ID
- OVERDUE_DATE

At each CALC_DATE a loan can have multiple OVERDUE_DATE.
How could be modeled this table using dimensional modeling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a **bridge table**. In a classic dimensional schema, each dimension attached to a fact table has a single value consistent with the fact table’s grain. But there are a number of situations in which a dimension is legitimately multivalued. Like in your example, an loan can have many due date :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A dimensional model is designed based on the reporting/analytical requirements of your business, not on the structure of any source tables. Therefore, I'm afraid, your question is meaningless